# WCF response is invalid due to the unexpected string (WCF + JSON)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json

I have configured WCF service to work with the JSON.
I have a problem that all entries are escaped.

```
    [
   {
      "rel":"http:\/\/localhost:3354\/customer\/1\/order",
      "uri":"http:\/\/localhost:3354\/customer\/1\/order\/3"
   },
   {
      "rel":"http:\/\/localhost:3354\/customer\/1\/order",
      "uri":"http:\/\/localhost:3354\/customer\/1\/order\/5"
   },
   {
      "rel":"http:\/\/localhost:3354\/customer\/1\/order",
      "uri":"http:\/\/localhost:3354\/customer\/1\/order\/8"
   }
]
```

I am sure that message is valid, no need to escape it by default, is it possible to turn off escaping for some fields?

Comment: are you returning: 'http:\\localhost:3354\customer\1\order' or 'http://localhost:3354/customer/1/order'?

Comment: Sorry, just misstake in description here. Wcf returning 'localhost:3354/customer/1/order';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'\' is a control character in [JSON](http://www.json.org/). In order to include \ in a string you must escape it with the / character. Any JSON client should be able to correctly interpret the escaped characters so you don't need to (rather you MUST NOT) make any modifications to your WCF code.

Besides, Pradeep is right. URLs use forward slashes.

Comment: Yes. Thats right. Iphone developers managed to parse this string. So problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

[JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) escape slashes.

> **char**
>       any-Unicode-character-
>           except-"-or--or-
>           control-character
>       \"
>       \
>       \/
>       \b
>       \f
>       \n
>       \r
>       \t
>       \u four-hex-digits

So: "/" in C# becomes a '\/' in JSON

Answer (score 2):

> http:\localhost:3354\customer\1\order

Why are you using backslashes. Commonly used way is to have forward slashes. I hope making your URL as "http://localhost:3354/customer/1/order" would solve the problem.

Comment: yes that was misstake here in issue description. On server i have url http://localhost:3354/customer/1/order